# Rendering colors to command line from html?

Tags: html, curl, ansi-colors, httpie

I've tried using HTTPie and Curl, but neither appear to support the following scenario.

```
curl somesite.com/somefile.html
<span style="color: blue;">I am blue!</span>
```

I'm in control of the site, so I can use any markup I'd like, but I was hoping there was something that did something like the above, which is to say take downloaded HTML output, and render it in ANSI colors.

UPDATE:

This is a demo, I'll be running from a Mac, against a node.js end point.

In the demo, I'd like to execute a loop:

```
while true; do curl http://somesite.com; sleep 1; done
```

After running this for ~5 seconds, I'll change a setting on the server, that will change this output. So, something like this:

```
I am blue!
I am blue!
I am blue! (Change occurs)
I am green!
I am green!
I am green!
```

And so on. I'd like to make that output (inside a Mac console) to change to the color that it says here. I've tried passing through the ANSI color codes, but it doesn't render.

Comment: You want the console to show the `I am blue!` text in blue?

Comment: Yes, if possible. I don't care what the colors are, just need 3 or 4.

Comment: which console? linux/windows? If you are the one that controls the site - just use the console-chars for colors (and not HTML).

Comment: I need to run it as the output of a node.js server. However, the display will be on a Mac.

Comment: I'm not so sure I understand the problem

Comment: It looks like osx's console-colors works the same as bash. can you try put `\033[0;34m\033I'm Blue![0m` inside your `html` file and `curl` it from your mac?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129710/discussion-between-aronchick-and-dekel).

Comment: @Dekel that works for blue but [0m does not revert the color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer was (thanks to Dekel) that you basically have to hand it to xargs - curl doesn't do it itself.

Worse, Mac xargs is different than Linux.

Here's how I did it:

```
curl localhost | xargs -0 -I {} printf "{}";
```